# JavaScript - event owerriten by outer class element

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, data-layers

I am sending two events here one when clicking on the specific div to mark the start of using form elements and the second for a specific input field inside the div.

When the inner div is clicked, it shows up for a second and then gets overwritten by the outer class element again.

```
$$('.form-block-company-logo').on('click', function (event) {
            sendToDataLayer({'event': 'form_creation', 'form_name': 'company_logo_add', 'step': '1'});
        });

        $$('#logo-upload').on('click', function () {
            sendToDataLayer({'event': 'form_creation', 'form_name': 'company_logo_select', 'step': '2'});
        });
```

Specifically when clicking on it gets `#logo-upload` it triggers **company_logo_select** for a second then gets back to the **company_logo_add** event. How to resolve this issue?

Thanks

My HTML: https://codepen.io/Filip-Stojanovic-the-typescripter/pen/YzdzyvO

Comment: You need to call `stopPropagation()` on the event raise by the child element. See the duplicate for more information

Comment: Yes, but $$('#logo-upload').on('click', function (e) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation(); did not do it for me? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: In which case can you please edit your question to include the relevant HTML so we can see a working example of the issue

Comment: I have posted the HTML on codepen @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Using `stopPropagation()` works correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/1yzqL78m/. If it's not working for you then there's another underlying issue which you need to debug.